# spring cloud consul discovery acl for catalog services

Tags: spring-cloud

I have ACL on for Consul, and have tried many ways to specify the token to use for service discovery. The config ACL token works fine, and the discovery ACL token works for registration (I can see my services in the Consul UI). I see the code for AgentConsulClient.agentServiceRegister() supports the token with this:
UrlParameters tokenParam = token != null ? new SingleUrlParameters("token", token) : null;

Nothing similar is supported in CatalogConsulClient, as far as I can tell. When called from Spring Cloud's ConsulDiscoveryClient, no token is passed, regardless of how it is set. Logs show the call being made without the token, and getting back a valid response with none of the registered services listed. I don't see how to have ACL on for registration but off for discovery. What am I missing? Is nobody actually using ACL if using discovery? (It works fine in the development environment with no ACL). Do I need to edit the source to add the token support from the agent service to the catalog service? Has anybody had success doing that?

BTW, could not tag this with spring-cloud-consul. Add it if you can.

Comment: There is no `spring-cloud-consul` tag.

Comment: Actually, where are you seeing the issue?

Comment: The issue is that a registered service that appears in the Consul UI does not get a route added for it in Zuul. It looks like the client call to /v1/catalog/services does not include the ACL token. If I hit Consul with a /v1/catalog/services url that does include the ACL token, then I get the expected list of registered services, but I have not been able to figure out a way to make Spring Cloud Consul include the token parameter. It is entirely possible I am missing something obvious. Did you set up an ACL on discovery in Consul and have it work for you?

Comment: I cannot add a new tag, but spring-cloud-consul seems like an obvious candidate.

Comment: We're blocked by https://github.com/Ecwid/consul-api/pull/61

Comment: Thanks, did not find that issue in my searching. All that is needed here then is a reference to the version in which it is fixed, for posterity.

Comment: Looks like it got pulled into the 1.1.11 milestone.

Answer (score 0):

ACL support for Consul catalog services is in consul-api v1.1.11 and will be (I hope) part of spring-cloud-consul 1.0.3.RELEASE. The 1.0.2.RELEASE version still uses consul-api-1.1.10. Update: confirmed to be in Camden.SR3.

Gradle:
 'com.ecwid.consul:consul-api:1.1.11',
 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-consul-dependencies:1.0.3.RELEASE'